# invalid reference to FROM-clause entry

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, syntax-error

```
SELECT 
  elem AS choice_id, 
  count (elem) AS value 
FROM 
  report_response, 
  jsonb_array_elements (
    report_response.submission -> 'question_6' -> 'answer_choice_ids'
  ) with ordinality arr(elem, index) 
  LEFT JOIN trigger_contact ON report_response.trigger_contact_id = trigger_contact.id 
  LEFT JOIN contact ON trigger_contact.contact_id = contact.id 
WHERE 
  "report_response"."account_id" = 2 
  AND "report_response"."survey_id" = 1 
  AND NOT "report_response"."is_locked" 
  AND (
    (
      (
        (
          (contact.attrs ->> 'mobile'):: text IS NULL
        )
      )
    )
  ) 
GROUP BY 
  elem;
```

This query is throwing error

ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "report_response"
LINE 6:   LEFT JOIN trigger_contact ON report_response.trigger_conta...
^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "report_response", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

how to correct this query

Comment: Try moving `report_response,` to just above the `LEFT JOIN trigger_contact ON report_response. ...`. I'm guessing the `LEFT JOIN` is binding to the `jsonb_array_elements ()`.

Comment: Tried it is throwing `Missing From Clause` Error now

Comment: My usual process in this sort of situation is to start with a simple two table query and then add joins to verify. I would leave the `jsonb_array_elements ()` part out until you have verified the rest of the query.

Comment: Try replacing the comma after `from report_response` with `cross join lateral`.